# Adding multiple columns of of multiple row values into an array of custom type

Tags: excel, vba

I have a worksheet that tracks  student test scores and gpa information. The worksheet layout is as follows:

Student ID, Name, Test 1 Score, Test 2 Score, Final Exam Score, GPA and Final Score. There are 20 rows.

I need to get the student id, whether or not they took the final exam, the gpa and the final score and store them in an array of custom type. Then there will be a form where a student inputs their id and it retrieves the appropriate data from the array.

I put a sample two row table in and the vba code I have so far.

My question is how do i get this data into the Array?

I am totally confused at this point....

```html
<div id="good_5932" align=center x:publishsource="Excel">

<table border=0 cellpadding=0 cellspacing=0 width=611 class=xl635932
 style='border-collapse:collapse;table-layout:fixed;width:458pt'>
 <col class=xl635932 width=74 style='mso-width-source:userset;mso-width- 
 alt:
 2645;width:56pt'>
 <col class=xl635932 width=100 style='mso-width-source:userset;mso-width- 
 alt:
 3555;width:75pt'>
 <col class=xl635932 width=76 style='mso-width-source:userset;mso-width- 
 alt:
 2702;width:57pt'>
 <col class=xl635932 width=77 style='mso-width-source:userset;mso-width- 
 alt:
 2730;width:58pt'>
 <col class=xl635932 width=152 style='mso-width-source:userset;mso-width- 
 alt:
 5404;width:114pt'>
 <col class=xl635932 width=66 style='width:49pt'>
 <col class=xl695932 width=66 style='width:49pt'>
 <tr height=37 style='height:27.6pt'>
  <td height=37 class=xl655932 width=74 
  style='height:27.6pt;width:56pt'>Student
  ID</td>
  <td class=xl655932 width=100 style='border-left:none;width:75pt'>Student 
  Name</td>
  <td class=xl665932 width=76 style='border-left:none;width:57pt'>Test 1 
  Score</td>
  <td class=xl665932 width=77 style='border-left:none;width:58pt'>Test 2 
  Score</td>
  <td class=xl665932 width=152 style='border- 
 left:none;width:114pt'>Comprehensive
  Final</td>
  <td class=xl665932 width=66 style='border-left:none;width:49pt'>Student 
  GPA</td>
  <td class=xl685932 width=66 style='border-left:none;width:49pt'>Final 
  Score</td>
 </tr>
 <tr height=19 style='height:14.4pt'>
  <td height=19 class=xl645932 style='height:14.4pt;border- 
  top:none'>5</td>
  <td class=xl645932 style='border-top:none;border-left:none'>Joe<span
  style='mso-spacerun:yes'> </span></td>
  <td class=xl645932 style='border-top:none;border-left:none'>78</td>
  <td class=xl675932 style='border-top:none;border-left:none'>12</td>
  <td class=xl645932 style='border-top:none;border-left:none'>87</td>
  <td class=xl645932 style='border-top:none;border-left:none'>3.5</td>
  <td class=xl675932 style='border-top:none;border-left:none'>96</td>
 </tr>
 <tr height=19 style='height:14.4pt'>
  <td height=19 class=xl645932 style='height:14.4pt;border- 
  top:none'>7</td>
  <td class=xl645932 style='border-top:none;border-left:none'>Hans</td>
  <td class=xl645932 style='border-top:none;border-left:none'>80</td>
  <td class=xl675932 style='border-top:none;border-left:none'>98</td>
  <td class=xl645932 style='border-top:none;border-left:none'>98</td>
  <td class=xl645932 style='border-top:none;border-left:none'>3.7</td>
  <td class=xl675932 style='border-top:none;border-left:none'>98</td>
 </tr>
 <tr height=19 style='height:14.4pt'>
  <td height=19 class=xl645932 style='height:14.4pt;border- 
  top:none'>8</td>
  <td class=xl645932 style='border-top:none;border-left:none'>Ferris</td>
  <td class=xl645932 style='border-top:none;border-left:none'>92</td>
  <td class=xl675932 style='border-top:none;border-left:none'>56</td>
  <td class=xl645932 style='border-top:none;border-left:none'>51</td>
  <td class=xl645932 style='border-top:none;border-left:none'>3</td>
  <td class=xl675932 style='border-top:none;border-left:none'>66</td>
 </tr>
 <tr height=19 style='height:14.4pt'>
  <td height=19 class=xl645932 style='height:14.4pt;border- 
  top:none'>10</td>
  <td class=xl645932 style='border-top:none;border-left:none'>Mike</td>
  <td class=xl645932 style='border-top:none;border-left:none'>45</td>
  <td class=xl675932 style='border-top:none;border-left:none'>87</td>
  <td class=xl645932 style='border-top:none;border-left:none'>87</td>
  <td class=xl645932 style='border-top:none;border-left:none'>2.6</td>
  <td class=xl675932 style='border-top:none;border-left:none'>87</td>
 </tr>
 <tr height=19 style='height:14.4pt'>
  <td height=19 class=xl645932 style='height:14.4pt;border- 
  top:none'>15</td>
  <td class=xl645932 style='border-top:none;border-left:none'>Lauren</td>
  <td class=xl645932 style='border-top:none;border-left:none'>98</td>
  <td class=xl675932 style='border-top:none;border-left:none'>49</td>
  <td class=xl645932 style='border-top:none;border-left:none'>89</td>
  <td class=xl645932 style='border-top:none;border-left:none'>4</td>
  <td class=xl675932 style='border-top:none;border-left:none'>92</td>
 </tr>
 <tr height=19 style='height:14.4pt'>
  <td height=19 class=xl645932 style='height:14.4pt;border- 
 top:none'>62</td>
  <td class=xl645932 style='border-top:none;border-left:none'>Larry</td>
  <td class=xl645932 style='border-top:none;border-left:none'>75</td>
  <td class=xl675932 style='border-top:none;border-left:none'>85</td>
  <td class=xl645932 style='border-top:none;border-left:none'>65</td>
  <td class=xl645932 style='border-top:none;border-left:none'>3.9</td>
  <td class=xl675932 style='border-top:none;border-left:none'>75</td>
 </tr>
 <tr height=19 style='height:14.4pt'>
  <td height=19 class=xl645932 style='height:14.4pt;border- 
 top:none'>68</td>
  <td class=xl645932 style='border-top:none;border-left:none'>Tony</td>
  <td class=xl645932 style='border-top:none;border-left:none'>48</td>
  <td class=xl675932 style='border-top:none;border-left:none'>87</td>
  <td class=xl645932 style='border-top:none;border-left:none'>89</td>
  <td class=xl645932 style='border-top:none;border-left:none'>3.5</td>
  <td class=xl675932 style='border-top:none;border-left:none'>96</td>
 </tr>
 <tr height=19 style='height:14.4pt'>
  <td height=19 class=xl645932 style='height:14.4pt;border- 
 top:none'>85</td>
  <td class=xl645932 style='border-top:none;border-left:none'>Kevin</td>
  <td class=xl645932 style='border-top:none;border-left:none'>68</td>
  <td class=xl675932 style='border-top:none;border-left:none'>83</td>
  <td class=xl645932 style='border-top:none;border-left:none'>79</td>
  <td class=xl645932 style='border-top:none;border-left:none'>3.2</td>
  <td class=xl675932 style='border-top:none;border-left:none'>80</td>
 </tr>
 <tr height=19 style='height:14.4pt'>
  <td height=19 class=xl645932 style='height:14.4pt;border- 
  top:none'>98</td>
  <td class=xl645932 style='border-top:none;border-left:none'>Sam</td>
  <td class=xl645932 style='border-top:none;border-left:none'>59</td>
  <td class=xl675932 style='border-top:none;border-left:none'>62</td>
  <td class=xl645932 style='border-top:none;border-left:none'>98</td>
  <td class=xl645932 style='border-top:none;border-left:none'>3.6</td>
  <td class=xl675932 style='border-top:none;border-left:none'>87</td>
 </tr>
 <tr height=19 style='height:14.4pt'>
  <td height=19 class=xl645932 style='height:14.4pt;border- 
 top:none'>101</td>
  <td class=xl645932 style='border-top:none;border-left:none'>Zibin</td>
  <td class=xl645932 style='border-top:none;border-left:none'>63</td>
  <td class=xl675932 style='border-top:none;border-left:none'>68</td>
  <td class=xl645932 style='border-top:none;border-left:none'>95</td>
  <td class=xl645932 style='border-top:none;border-left:none'>3.5</td>
  <td class=xl675932 style='border-top:none;border-left:none'>88</td>
 </tr>
 <tr height=19 style='height:14.4pt'>
  <td height=19 class=xl645932 style='height:14.4pt;border- 
  top:none'>105</td>
  <td class=xl645932 style='border-top:none;border-left:none'>Ran</td>
  <td class=xl645932 style='border-top:none;border-left:none'>49</td>
  <td class=xl675932 style='border-top:none;border-left:none'>59</td>
  <td class=xl645932 style='border-top:none;border-left:none'>94</td>
  <td class=xl645932 style='border-top:none;border-left:none'>3.8</td>
  <td class=xl675932 style='border-top:none;border-left:none'>85</td>
 </tr>
 <tr height=19 style='height:14.4pt'>
  <td height=19 class=xl645932 style='height:14.4pt;border- 
  top:none'>108</td>
  <td class=xl645932 style='border-top:none;border-left:none'>Donia</td>
  <td class=xl645932 style='border-top:none;border-left:none'>87</td>
  <td class=xl675932 style='border-top:none;border-left:none'>12</td>
  <td class=xl645932 style='border-top:none;border-left:none'>92</td>
  <td class=xl645932 style='border-top:none;border-left:none'>2.9</td>
  <td class=xl675932 style='border-top:none;border-left:none'>104</td>
 </tr>
 <tr height=19 style='height:14.4pt'>
  <td height=19 class=xl645932 style='height:14.4pt;border- 
  top:none'>109</td>
  <td class=xl645932 style='border-top:none;border-left:none'>Kate</td>
  <td class=xl645932 style='border-top:none;border-left:none'>85</td>
  <td class=xl675932 style='border-top:none;border-left:none'>57</td>
  <td class=xl645932 style='border-top:none;border-left:none'>49</td>
  <td class=xl645932 style='border-top:none;border-left:none'>2.6</td>
  <td class=xl675932 style='border-top:none;border-left:none'>64</td>
 </tr>
 <tr height=19 style='height:14.4pt'>
  <td height=19 class=xl645932 style='height:14.4pt;border- 
  top:none'>110</td>
  <td class=xl645932 style='border-top:none;border-left:none'>Sahar</td>
  <td class=xl645932 style='border-top:none;border-left:none'>45</td>
  <td class=xl675932 style='border-top:none;border-left:none'>59</td>
  <td class=xl645932 style='border-top:none;border-left:none'>87</td>
  <td class=xl645932 style='border-top:none;border-left:none'>2.7</td>
  <td class=xl675932 style='border-top:none;border-left:none'>81</td>
 </tr>
 <tr height=19 style='height:14.4pt'>
  <td height=19 class=xl645932 style='height:14.4pt;border- 
  top:none'>115</td>
  <td class=xl645932 style='border-top:none;border-left:none'>Milos</td>
  <td class=xl645932 style='border-top:none;border-left:none'>21</td>
  <td class=xl675932 style='border-top:none;border-left:none'>49</td>
  <td class=xl645932 style='border-top:none;border-left:none'>&nbsp;</td>
  <td class=xl645932 style='border-top:none;border-left:none'>3.8</td>
  <td class=xl675932 style='border-top:none;border-left:none'>35</td>
 </tr>
 <tr height=19 style='height:14.4pt'>
  <td height=19 class=xl645932 style='height:14.4pt;border- 
  top:none'>125</td>
  <td class=xl645932 style='border-top:none;border-left:none'>Brian</td>
  <td class=xl645932 style='border-top:none;border-left:none'>49</td>
  <td class=xl675932 style='border-top:none;border-left:none'>98</td>
  <td class=xl645932 style='border-top:none;border-left:none'>&nbsp;</td>
  <td class=xl645932 style='border-top:none;border-left:none'>3.9</td>
  <td class=xl675932 style='border-top:none;border-left:none'>74</td>
 </tr>
 <tr height=19 style='height:14.4pt'>
  <td height=19 class=xl645932 style='height:14.4pt;border- 
 top:none'>130</td>
  <td class=xl645932 style='border-top:none;border-left:none'>Zane</td>
  <td class=xl645932 style='border-top:none;border-left:none'>34</td>
  <td class=xl675932 style='border-top:none;border-left:none'>38</td>
  <td class=xl645932 style='border-top:none;border-left:none'>&nbsp;</td>
  <td class=xl645932 style='border-top:none;border-left:none'>3.2</td>
  <td class=xl675932 style='border-top:none;border-left:none'>36</td>
 </tr>

 <tr height=19 style='height:14.4pt'>
  <td height=19 class=xl645932 style='height:14.4pt;border- 
  top:none'>145</td>
  <td class=xl645932 style='border-top:none;border-left:none'>Istiak</td>
  <td class=xl645932 style='border-top:none;border-left:none'>91</td>
  <td class=xl675932 style='border-top:none;border-left:none'>87</td>
  <td class=xl645932 style='border-top:none;border-left:none'>&nbsp;</td>
  <td class=xl645932 style='border-top:none;border-left:none'>3.1</td>
  <td class=xl675932 style='border-top:none;border-left:none'>89</td>

 </tr>
 <tr height=19 style='height:14.4pt'>
  <td height=19 class=xl645932 style='height:14.4pt;border- 
  top:none'>150</td>
  <td class=xl645932 style='border-top:none;border-left:none'>Kumari</td>
  <td class=xl645932 style='border-top:none;border-left:none'>100</td>
  <td class=xl675932 style='border-top:none;border-left:none'>78</td>
  <td class=xl645932 style='border-top:none;border-left:none'>&nbsp;</td>
  <td class=xl645932 style='border-top:none;border-left:none'>3</td>
  <td class=xl675932 style='border-top:none;border-left:none'>89</td>
 </tr>
 <tr height=19 style='height:14.4pt'>
  <td height=19 class=xl645932 style='height:14.4pt;border- 
  top:none'>186</td>
  <td class=xl645932 style='border-top:none;border-left:none'>John</td>
  <td class=xl645932 style='border-top:none;border-left:none'>19</td>
  <td class=xl675932 style='border-top:none;border-left:none'>76</td>
  <td class=xl645932 style='border-top:none;border-left:none'>&nbsp;</td>
  <td class=xl645932 style='border-top:none;border-left:none'>2.9</td>
  <td class=xl675932 style='border-top:none;border-left:none'>48</td>
 </tr>
 <![if supportMisalignedColumns]>
 <tr height=0 style='display:none'>
  <td width=74 style='width:56pt'></td>
  <td width=100 style='width:75pt'></td>
  <td width=76 style='width:57pt'></td>
  <td width=77 style='width:58pt'></td>
  <td width=152 style='width:114pt'></td>
  <td width=66 style='width:49pt'></td>
  <td width=66 style='width:49pt'></td>
 </tr>
 <![endif]>
</table>

</div>
```

```
Option Explicit

'***** MyType as an array
Public Type Student
StudentID As Integer ' Student ID
FinalScore As Integer ' Studnts final score
ComprehensiveTaker As Integer ' Comprehensivetaker
StudentGPA As Double ' Student's GPA
End Type

Public CEEStudent(20) As Student

Public Sub fillCEEStudent()

    Dim j As Long, i As Long, CEEStudent(20) As Student
            j = 0
            i = 3

          If j < 21 And i < 23 Then
            j = j
            i = i

            CEEStudent(j).StudentID = Sheets("Question1").Cells(i, 3).Value
            CEEStudent(j).ComprehensiveTaker = IIf(Sheets("Question1").Cells(i, 7).Value <> "", 1, 0)
            CEEStudent(j).StudentGPA = Sheets("Question1").Cells(i, 8).Value
            CEEStudent(j).FinalScore = Sheets("Question1").Cells(i, 9).Value
          Else:
            j = 0
            i = 3

         End If

    Dim formNum As Integer, formScore As Integer, formGPA As Double, formInput As String

    With VBAProject.UserForm1

        formInput = 5 'VBAProject.UserForm1.TextBox1.Value

        If IsNumeric(formInput) Then
            formNum = formInput
        Else
            formNum = 0
        End If

        If formInput <> "" And formNum > 0 Then
                If CEEStudent(j).StudentID > formNum Or CEEStudent(j).StudentID < formNum Then
                    VBAProject.UserForm1.TextBox2.Text = CStr(" ")
                    VBAProject.UserForm1.BackColor = vbRed
                    VBAProject.UserForm1.StudentID.BackColor = vbRed
                    VBAProject.UserForm1.TestScore.BackColor = vbRed
                    VBAProject.UserForm1.GPA.BackColor = vbRed
                    VBAProject.UserForm1.TextBox2.BackColor = vbRed
                    VBAProject.UserForm1.TextBox3.BackColor = vbRed
                Else:
                    VBAProject.UserForm1.TextBox2.Text = CStr(CEEStudent(j).FinalScore)
                    VBAProject.UserForm1.TextBox3.Text = CStr(CEEStudent(j).StudentGPA)
                End If
        Else:
            formScore = 0
        End If

        VBAProject.UserForm1.TextBox2.Text = CStr(formScore)
        VBAProject.UserForm1.TextBox3.Text = CStr(formGPA)

        If VBAProject.UserForm1.TextBox2.Text >= 95 Then
           VBAProject.UserForm1.BackColor = vbGreen
           VBAProject.UserForm1.TextBox2.BackColor = vbGreen
           VBAProject.UserForm1.TextBox3.BackColor = vbGreen


        If VBAProject.UserForm1.TextBox2.Text < 95 And VBAProject.UserForm1.TextBox3.Text > 3.5 Then
           VBAProject.UserForm1.BackColor = vbBlue
           VBAProject.UserForm1.TextBox2.BackColor = Gray
           VBAProject.UserForm1.TextBox3.BackColor = Gray
        Else:
           VBAProject.UserForm1.BackColor = Gray
           VBAProject.UserForm1.TextBox2.BackColor = Gray
           VBAProject.UserForm1.TextBox3.BackColor = Gray

        End If
    End If
  End With
End Sub
```

****EDIT****
I added the HTML for the actual table in the snippet above... The table is in the worksheet named Question1 and starts with C2 being "Student ID" and then C3 being the first row of students.

The above code compiles and runs but is not returning the Values. I added a button to open userForm1 on Sheet("Question2"), click it and the form opens. enter the number 5 for student ID (Which matches my first row student info) and it returns 0 for score and GPA when it should return the actual figures.

So, we are getting somewhere....

Array :

CEEStudent  {

```
(0)StudentID : 5
   FinalScore : 96
   ComprehensiveTaker : 1
   StudentGPA : 3.6

(1)StudentID : 7
   FinalScore : 88
   ComprehensiveTaker : 1
   StudentGPA : 3.8
```

Comment: Is there a problem with your existing code?

Comment: It's not complete, as far as I know... All I did was wrap the i variable for loop inside of the j variable for loop and defined the values for the array...

Comment: you have to be careful of where you want to get your info from when you say  With ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Question2"), then you have assignments and references inside a loop.  I would rather you type it out Explicitly what sheet until it works and then you can roll back through and use your WITH statements so you know exactly where the data is that you are referencing and exactly where you want it placed.

Comment: I agree with you on this... see below comments... But how do i explicitly call the userform1?  I tried Forms.UserForm1... but it did not work...

Answer (score 1):

Something like this should work:

```
Public CEEStudent() As Student


'***** MyType as an array
Public Sub fillCEEStudent()
    Dim j As Long, i As Long

    ReDim CEEStudent(20)

    With ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Question1")
        j = 0
        For i = 3 To 22
            'might need to tweak the column positions
            CEEStudent(j).StudentID = .Cells(i, "C").Value
            CEEStudent(j).StudentGPA = .Cells(i, "H").Value
            CEEStudent(j).ComprehensiveTaker = IIf(.Cells(i, "G").Value <> "", 1, 0)
            CEEStudent(j).FinalScore = .Cells(i, "I").Value
            j = j + 1
        Next i
    End With
End Sub
```

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/186582/discussion-on-answer-by-tim-williams-adding-multiple-columns-of-of-multiple-row).

Answer (score 0):

I don't really understand the Public student stuff at the beginning, and I don't think it is necessary to do what you need.  As long as you know how to setup a userform (which I know nothing about) The following code should do what you need.

```
sub macro()

Dim id as int, CEEEStudent() as variant, idRow as long, ws1 as Worksheet, ws2 as Worksheet

Set ws1 = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Question 1")
Set ws2 = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet where data goes")

'insert code for a userform and store studentid = id here
id = ?


'this checks each row on the sheet and compares it to id, when it finds a match the row is stored to idRow
for x = 1 to Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row
    if id = ws1.cells(x, 1) Then
    idRow = x
    Else:
    End if
next x

'this stores the student's results to CEEEStudent(), each time a new student logs in it will overwrite the data from the previous student 
CEEEStudent(0) = ws1.Cells(idRow, 1).value
CEEEStudent(1) = ws1.Cells(idRow, 5).value
CEEEStudent(2) = ws1.Cells(idRow, 6).value
CEEEStudent(3) = ws1.Cells(idRow, 7).value

ws2.activate

'This sets the value and headers that the student will see.  Again this will be overwritten after every login.

ws2.Cells(1, 1).Value = "Student ID"
ws2.Cells(2, 1).Value = CEEEStudent(0)

ws2.Cells(1, 2).Value = "Final Exam"
ws2.Cells(2, 2).Value = CEEEStudent(1)

ws2.Cells(1, 3).Value = "GPA"
ws2.Cells(2, 3).Value = CEEEStudent(2)

ws2.Cells(1, 4).Value = "Final Score"
ws2.Cells(2, 4).Value = CEEEStudent(3)




end sub
```

EDIT 1

```
Public Type Student
StudentID As Integer ' Student ID
FinalScore As Integer ' Studnts final score
ComprehensiveTaker As Integer ' Comprehensivetaker
StudentGPA As Double ' Student's GPA
End Type

Public CEEStudent(20) As Student

public Sub test()

Cells(1, 1).Value = CEEStudent(20).StudentID 
Cells(1, 2).Value = CEEStudent(20).StudentGPA 
Cells(1, 3).Value = CEEStudent(20).ComprehensiveTaker 
Cells(1, 4).Value = CEEStudent(20).FinalScore                             

End sub
```

Comment: The Custom Type and definitions are required unfortunately. I have been working on it,  but keep getting an "Out of Range error" on the line where you first attempt to assign a value to CEEStudent(0).

Comment: BTW, it is only 2 E's i CEEStudent... Also, I did try running it as you typed it above and got the same error. The only difference is that I am declaring CEEStudent as type Student, which is defined publicly.

I think the issue is that you are comparing studentID to the actual row number, if I am correct. But the Student IDs are random numbers between 5 and 186 and not in any articular order (though they could be sorted as such.

Comment: I understand now; I didn't realize that CEEStudent was defined elsewhere.  Can you open a blank workbook and see if you can run the macro in edit 1?

Comment: I get the error 'Sub or Function Not Defined' and it highlights the first CeeStudent(20) line in test()

Comment: Sorry I had them backwards.  I fixed it in EDIT1.

Comment: ok, will try it now. I added the original code that performs the intitial calculations on wb1... not thT IT WILL DIRECTLY HELP...

Comment: Same thing: 'Compile Error Sub or Function not Defined' Highlights the first CEEStudent

Comment: This is driving me nuts... I have to follow these parameters: CEEStudent must be declared as a public variable of the type Student and then a userform that allows a user to input their student ID and displays back the corresponding final score and gpa of the student using the data in the workbook "Question1", which the first row of data starts at C3 and goes down to C22 / Columns C - I